# onload not working when routing to a new page

Tags: javascript, onload

Suppose I am at the "Home" page of a website. Now when I click on "AboutUs" link from the Home page itself, I want to change position on a DIV element on the "About Us" page. But nothing happens with the below code.

```
//HTML Code of Home page
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="AboutUs.html" onclick="NavTo();">About Us</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/javascript code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//javascript code.js
function NavTo() {
    document.getElementById("OurServices").onload = function() {
        alert("hello");
        document.getElementById("OurServices").style.position = "fixed";
    }
}
```

I have put the "alert" code so that I get to know if at all something is getting executed within that function or not. But no alert is getting displayed, which means that the function is not getting executed.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: because you are redirected before alert can occur.

Comment: Body tag must be added after head tag and inner HTML tag.

Comment: sorry guys it was a typo. In my actual html, I did not put the <head> inside the <body>. I have corrected the same above too now. I have also specified the question more precisely as to what is required. Previously I thought it'd be easier to get the solution if I had made the question a bit generic. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your alert code in the AboutUs.html file.

Comment: I can't do that. Actaully there is more than one way to reach the "About Us" page. But I want that the alert should be displayed only when routing through a particular option.

Comment: Then you could make the about.html page aware of what page called it and based on that call the alert message script.

Comment: Hi Peter,
This sounds like it would work for me. I am not aware though, as to how to make a page aware of what page called it. I'll try and figure out what code need to written. If you could suggest any command/code that could help me, it'd be great.

Comment: Sorry, just on mobile at the minute. But you could incorporate a query string in your href and extract it using javascript on the about.html page?

Comment: It worked. Honestly I heard the word "query string" for the first time. I am pretty new to coding; started learning around 2 months ago.
On the "Home" page, my href is now "AboutUs.html?section=OurServices"

And on "About Us" page, I wrote:

    <body onload="NavTo(document.URL);">

Thanks a lot for the solution

Answer (score 1):

This is because the page is already loaded when the js file is running.

1. A good practice is to put the external js file reference before the end of the body tag in your html file.
2. And please also make sure the html format is correct and please do not put the "head" tag into the "body" tag.
3. Also you need to remove the onload event trigger, because the event actually is triggered not by onload, but by click.

So to make your page works, the js file should be just like:

```
function NavTo(){
     alert("hello");
 };
```

And your html file should look like:

```
    //HTML Code of Home page
   <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
       <a href="AboutUs.html" onclick="NavTo();">About Us</a>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/javascript code.js"></script>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Actually I can't omit the "onload" part. I have modified the question to reflect, more precisely, of what is required.

Also, I put this <script> element as you suggested. But the onload still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Hearly: Thanks a lot for the answer. Below is the exact code:

```
//HTML Code of Home page
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="AboutUs.html?section=OurServices">About Us</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/javascript code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//HTML Code of About Us page
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="NavTo(document.URL);">
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/javascript code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//javascript code.js
function NavTo() {
var eqPosition = pageURL.indexOf("=");  //get the position number of "=" sign
var html_id = pageURL.substring(eqPosition+1,pageURL.length);  //get the string to the right side of the "=" sign
//few lines of required code
}
```